# home and zoom widget button in arcgis api js

Tags: arcgis-js-api

How to use this one?

[image: home button]

What is the name of this widget?

Comment: Looks custom made, here's a thread with some suggestions: https://geonet.esri.com/thread/107259#comment-402029

Comment: thank you, @chrki post your comment  to vote positive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a dedicated home button widget available ([4.x docs](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-Home.html), [3.x docs](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/homebutton-amd.html)) but it acts as a separate button and does not integrate into the zoom controls.

Judging from your screenshot that looks custom made (HTML element inserted into the zoom controls), there's a thread on Geonet with some similar looking suggestions: https://geonet.esri.com/thread/107259#comment-402029